# Unable to send message to group in SignalR

Tags: signalr

I am using SignalR library. I am running 3 instances of my application and then I add two users to a group named 'Test'. Now when i send message to 'Test' group, the message is not delivered at all.

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void send(string name, string message)
        {
            //This line of code is not working
            Clients.Group("test").broadcastMessage(message);


            //This is working
            //Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);

        }

        public void JoinGroup(string groupName)
        {
            Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

        }

        public void RemoveGroup(string groupName)
        {
            Groups.Remove(this.Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
        }
    }
```

//**Client side**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>SignalR Simple Chat</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            background-color: #99CCFF;
            border: thick solid #808080;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <input type="text" id="groupName" />
        <input type="button" id="joinGroup" value="Join" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="message" />
        <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
        <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
        <ul id="discussion">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/j`enter code here`query.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/signalr/hubs"></script>



</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.  
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages. 
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            // Html encode display name and message.  
            var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
            // Add the message to the page.  
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
        };
        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages. 
        $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
        // Set initial focus to message input box.   
        $('#message').focus();
        // Start the connection. 
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub.  
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.  
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });


            $('#joinGroup').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub.  
                chat.server.joinGroup($('#groupName').val());
            });
        });
    });

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the **'broadcastMessage'** on the client was expecting two parameter and i was passing only one parameter while calling **'broadcastMessage'** using group.

Changing

```
'Clients.Group("test").broadcastMessage(message);'

 to 

'Clients.Group("test").broadcastMessage(name, message);' worked.
```